# Passing value from Default.aspx to App or Main page in silverlight3

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-3.0, ip

I'm using silverlight3 and vb.net..I want to pass the value from `Default.aspx` to my App or Main page. I wrote the code in my `default.aspx` page which it is returning the local ip address of the client System, I would like that same address to be used in my silverlight pages.

### VB code

```
Dim clientIPAddress = System.Net.Dns
    .GetHostAddresses(strHostName).GetValue(0).ToString()
```

This `clientIPAddress` will get the local ip of the client which is like `192.168.1.12`. Now i want this value to be passed to my main page.

Please any one help to pass this value from `default.aspx` to my main page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your default.aspx page will have an `<object>` tag where the Silverlight plugin is loaded.  You can added a `<param name="initParams` value="clientID=192.168.1.12"`>` so it looks something like:-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Silverlight3App.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <param name="initParams` value="clientID=192.168.1.12"`>
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Except of course you wouldn't hardcode the IP address but you'd inject that with some VB.NET code (I don't do VB.NET).

The initParams parameter is a set of name=value pairs that are exposed in Silverlight as a `IDictionary(Of String, String)`.  You can get this dictionary from the Application Startup event arguments or from `Application.Current.Host.InitParams`.